# Best way to send movement commands to pi robot over network from computer

Tags: raspbian, networking, robotics

I am planning a project in which I will be controlling a robot I will make from my laptop. I am connected to the pi over an ad hoc network. I want to be able to give it simple key board commands (like WASD in a videogame) to move in different directions. The only way I can think of doing this is connecting to the pi through a VNC server and setting up this interaction in python. Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: Ah, just one brainstorming suggestion. (1)  Master SBC = Rpi3/4, (2) Slave WiFi/sensor/actuator (servo etc) controller = Cortex M0, ESP8266. (3) Programming language = circuit python/micro python (google AdaFruit)  So config = Rpi talks to ESP8266, which in turn talks to laptop/smart phone. Have a nice project, cheers.

Comment: I couldn't think of a worse way. See https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour to see how this site works.

Comment: MQTT messages from laptop to Pi?

Comment: @CoderMike I did some research and that actually seems like it could work. I would just make my computer the broker and the publisher while the pi is the subscriber right?

Comment: @Nicokofi, your are welcome. Have a nice project. Cheers.